# Send callback to non isolated scope child

Tags: angularjs, binding, callback, angularjs-scope

I need to add a callback to a child directive, that is not an isolated scope. I know you can do it with an isolated scope, you can also use scope.$parent to access it, however this isn't always correct if the immediate parent is the wrong parent.

```
myApp.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.callback = function(msg) {
       alert(msg);
      }
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var msg = 'from child';
      if (angular.isDefined(attrs.callback)) {
         scope.$parent.$apply(attr.callback);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This works, however I don't like it, I hate having to manually trigger $apply or $digest, also hate even more trying to access scope.$parent, as this is not always the intended scope...

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: All I did was removing the `Angular` tag because it is for Angular >= 2.0.0 and your question is obviously about Angularjs 1.x.x. I also didn't post an answer. There are thousands of people watching the Angular tags, not only me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that isolated scopes do not prototypically inherit, if you need to parse from an isolated scope to a child directive (nested), you'll need to manually transclude the content and use the isolated scope as the context.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myWrapperDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      transclude: true,
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $null, $transclude) {
        $scope.name= 'test';
        $transclude($scope, function(clone) {
          $element.append(clone);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('myNestedDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // now child directive and parent share same scope.
        console.log($scope.name);
      }
    };
  });
```

Template:

```
<div my-wrapper-directive>
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <div my-nested-directive>
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xM92P/786/